# How to access terabytes of data sitting in cloud quickly?

Tags: database, http, amazon-s3, python-requests, gcloud

We have Terabytes of data sitting in the google hard drives. Initially, since we were using google cloud VMs, so we were doing development work in the cloud and were able to access the data.

Now, we bought our own servers where our application is running and we are bringing the data to our local disks which would be accessed by our application. The things is transferring the data especially terabytes on network using `scp` is quite slow. Can anyone suggest a way to fix this issue?

What I am thinking is there isn't a way that we can keep running a script waiting for a request on the google cloud instance(it send the requested data over HTTP!), and from local_server, we can request for data at a time!
I know this again is happening over the network but, I think we can scale in this approach, but I could be wrong!. it's kind of client-server(1:1) layout using in building interaction between frontend and backend! any suggestions?

- Would that be slow? slower than bringing the data using SCP!

Comment: Something to keep in mind before you encounter an unpleasant surprise is that it costs around $120 to export each terabyte of data from GCP unless you have other arrangements that allow you to avoid standard egress pricing.  Aggressive compression will save costs and time, if that's possible for the data in question.

Comment: ugh! That's expensive! Wasn't aware of it. There isn't a way to buy the hard disk directly from GCP. I mean company's have Petabytes of data stored on the cloud, there should be an option? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you will have to eat up that one-time cost of bringing data from cloud to local.  I doubt google will give a discount on that as you are taking away the business from them. Also, regarding the approach you mentioned, you can scale the SCP approach as well. Have more machines doing SCP on different files or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to export the data from a VM Instance disk or from a Google Cloud Storage Service like Data Store or cloud SQL?

Comment: @rsalinas, from VM!

Answer (score 0):

You could download the full VM disk and mount int on you servers or download the disk then just copy the data and delete the VM disk. For any case you should follow the next steps:

1. [Create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of your VM which will have all the data.
2. [Build](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images) and [export](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) the VM image to your servers.
3. Run the image on your servers according to [GCE requirements](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/import-existing-image#requirements).

It would take a lot less of time, since you're doing it on on premises and avoiding network traffic.